# Mounting a Micro SD card

Tags: mount, sd-card, micro-sd

I'm trying to mount a Micro SD card. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2. When I put a new micro SD card in, it automatically mounts and shows all files.

When I run: `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/micro && cd /media/micro`, the commands work and shows the directory of the sd card.

When I put this card into my dash cam it, reformats it. I put the card in a windows machine it shows it as a FAT32 file system and shows all the video files.  I can transfer to a thumb drive and it read all files fine on my Linux machine.

However When I put the SD card in my Linux laptop nothing. The command `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/micro` I get:

```
aaron@aaron-K46CA:/media/micro$ sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/micro 
mount: /media/micro: more filesystems detected on /dev/mmcblk0p1; use -t <type> or wipefs(8).

Running: aaron@aaron-K46CA:~$ sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0 /media/micro
[sudo] password for aaron: 
mount: /media/micro: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mmcblk0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

If I run sudo fdisk -l, I get:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 29.74 GiB, 31914983424 bytes, 62333952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you get after you run sudo lsblk   ?  I suspect that you will get more than one disk partition showing up beneath mmcblk0

Comment: You can got to the top left corner of your screen  "Activities" and search for "Disks"  aka "Gnome Disks" .  It will tell you what sort of format it has detected for the partitions  on your SD card, how large they are, etc.  I hope this will give you the idea of how to mount the card and get what you need instead of having to run to a windows machine to transfer your dash cam videos.

Comment: Running sudo lsbik: 
mmcblk0     179:0    0  29.7G  1 disk 
└─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  29.7G  1 part

Comment: When I look22.4G  0 dis at "Disks"  I get:  Two partitions of the 32gb sd card, sdb           (4mbfree space) mmcblk0    and (partition 1, 32gb, unknown, and Read Only) mmcblk0p1

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
$ sudo mount -t vfat  /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/micro   #fat32
```

OR

```
$ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g  /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/micro    #ntfs
```

should work